# Laravel can't login with custom table name and fields

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to login with laravel with a custom table named `utilisateurs` with field `courriel` as username and `motdepasse` as password.

```
if(Auth::attempt(['courriel' => $request->courriel, 'motdepasse' => $request->motdepasse]))
{     
    return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
}

return redirect('/')->with(['error' => 'Impossible de se connecter avec ces identifiants']);
```

The Auth:attempt() always return false. The fields are okay, I've tried multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you changed migration files and model files for table name changes ? i suppose that you have done needed things like : changing User.php model file.

Comment: also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449076/laravel-5-4-change-authentication-users-table-name.

Comment: Yes, I've added `public $table = 'utilisateurs` in my `User.php` file

Comment: protected $table = 'utilisateurs'; is what you want I believe.

Comment: yep but it probably does not explain why this is not working, but thanks

Comment: `User.php` by default use `users` table. so , if we want to use custom table (as you are doing `utilisateurs`) than it is needed to define in model to interact with custom table. hope it makes sense.