# Changing Laravel auth table name and column names

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I want to change the table name and some column names of laravel auth table.

- Change table name from 'users' to 'accounts'
- Change table column name from 'name' to 'username'
- Change table column name from 'email' to 'email_addr'
- Change table column name from 'updated_at' to 'last_updated_at'

What steps do I take or which code do I edit without breaking something?

I tried this before, and registration worked, but login didn't. Whenever I tried to log in, I got redirected back to the login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.4 change authentication users table name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449076/laravel-5-4-change-authentication-users-table-name)

Comment: This may also help: https://www.5balloons.info/changing-authentication-table-laravel/

Answer (score 15):

You can follow the below given steps:

1. Create/modify migration to change the **users** table to **accounts**
2. Create migration to change the column name as per your requirements for table **accounts**. Make sure this model call is extends `Authenticatable`
3. Create model class for **accounts** table.
4. Make sure to add **fillable** and **hidden** attributes of table.
5. Now check the **login.blade.php** file and change the `email` input text field name to `email_address`.

With the above all steps, we are ready with **View** part now let's start with customising the **Auth**

1. Now open **config/auth.php**

   - Change from  `'model' => App\User::class,` to `'model' => App\Account:class` inside `providers` array.
2. Now we need to add new function inside **app/Http/Auth/LoginController.php** like below:

`public function username(){ return 'email_address'; // this string is column of accounts table which we are going use for login }`

Now we are done with all adjustment, you can test the functionality.

I have tested the functionality and its working like charm :)

Comment: Thanks for adding public function username(){ return 'email_addr'; }. Solved my problem.

Comment: I also updated RegisterController class method #validator().  

            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:accounts'],

Answer (score 7):

you have to extend "Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User" in your Account model.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Account extends Authenticatable
{ 
  use Notifiable;

  //code here
  public function getEmailAttribute() {
      return $this->email_addr;
  }

  public function setEmailAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['email_addr'] = strtolower($value);
  }
}
```

and change in configuration file in "config/auth.php" in providers array

```
'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Account::class,  //replace User to Account
    ],
```

Comment: What of the columns? How do I go about that?

Comment: you have to customised them in Account model

Comment: How to customize them? What of templates, controllers?

Comment: are you using default login route

Comment: Can i have **both models** as `Authenticatable`