# How to completely change the auth table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication

I have `accounts` table in which I want to be **Authenticatable** and I done to this, already did the answer of *@PintuKumar* in this [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626323/changing-laravel-auth-table-name-and-column-names) and it's working fine.

My issue here, the line below is working

```
auth()->user()->email
```

But what I wanted is the line below, when I try it, it doesn't work

```
auth()->account()->email
```

It returns an error below:

> Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::account does not exist. (View: D:\workspace\laravel\blog\resources\views\home.blade.php)

Anyone, does know how to change function name from user to *custom*? I'm really stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method name does not matter, `user` method does not mean your authentication guards fetches a `App\User`, it fetches the entity authenticated by this guard, whatever it is.

If you really want to do this (notice that it would be nothing more than an alias), you have to inherit your session guard and add this method

```php
public function account()
{
    return $this->user();
}
```

But once again it is a bad idea, particularly because you ignore a method which is implemented by every guard. If one day you decide to change the used guard, your code will break for the same reason.

Comment: thanks for the idea Sir, now I will not make any modification, I will stick to user(). thanks for helpful suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

Well, never done this before, but you can go to `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php` and change `user()` to the desired name. Personally, for tests, I would copy the whole function, change to `account()` but keep `users()` in case something goes wrong.

Comment: `vendor` directory must not be changed like that because it is gitignored and any update will erase the change.

Comment: It's true. But your question points to ```Auth()```. Use the ```app/User``` instead.

Comment: @hmrneves already tried that, another error returned **Class Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard::user)**

Comment: It's normal, you are trying to mess with the framework. Please read all the answers and comments.